# Плавная замена содержимого блока div

Tags: jquery, javascript

У меня есть два блока div, в которых нужно менять содержание (картинки, текст) каждые 4 секунды, т.е. зациклить. Я пробовал применить скрипт jQuery cycle. Вот [сайт](http://www.mapsky.ru/), где я применил cycle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var parentTaglineEl = $('#ticker1,#ticker2');
        parentTaglineEl.cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 1000,
            timeout: 6000,
            random:  0
        });
    });
```

Скрипт работает, вот только при загрузке страницы на секунду показывает всё содержимое, наверно, cycle тяжело грузится.

**Вопрос:**

Существует альтернативный способ менять содержимое блока `div`? Может, у кого завалялся такой скрипт, поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что содержимое не показывалось при загрузке страницы, нужно чтобы css грузился раньше JS и в css было:

`#ticker1,#ticker2 {display: none;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как написал выше, можно сделать и самому, вот такой [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/1vzdyLd7/2/) набросал с заменой текстовых блоков, думаю, проблем с картинками тоже не будет.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="text">
    <div class="text-block">Текст 1</div>
    <div class="text-block">Текст 2</div>
    <div class="text-block">Текст 3</div>
    <div class="text-block">Текст 4</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.text .text-block').eq(0).addClass("active").fadeIn(1000); // Показываем первый блок, можно и не первый, если прописать нужную цифру в eq()
    setInterval('blockAnimate();', 5000); // Вызываем функцию для смены блока каждые 5 секунд
});

// Функция для смены блоков, показывает блоки по очереди, начальный блок задаётся выше
function blockAnimate() {
    var length = $('.text .text-block').length - 1;
    $('.text .text-block').each(function(index) {
        if($(this).hasClass('active') && index != length) {
            $(this).removeClass("active").fadeOut(1000).next('.text-block').addClass("active").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
            return false;
        } else if (index == length) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').fadeOut(1000);
            $('.text .text-block').eq(0).addClass("active").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

**UPD**

Убрал задержки в анимации и вставил картинки вместо текста, код почти не изменился (не вижу смысла его выкладывать ещё раз), поэтому вот [ссылка на итоговой пример](http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/1vzdyLd7/3/)

Comment: @MasterAlex 
Не хватает опции затухания. Дело в том, что блок пропадает совсем и надолго, это означает, что плавной замены содержимого нет, есть исчезновение одного и появление другого блока. Посмотрите на сайте, как это происходит с использованием cycle. Нужна плавная замена, а не моргание, но за скрипт спасибо, я от такой замены отказался, сильно моргает, отрицательно действует на глаза http://jsfiddle.net/9b27ps4q/light/

Comment: Больше нет вариантов нИ у кого? Скрипт @MasterAlex не подходит.

Comment: @Viher, обновил ответ, сделать нужный эффект в анимации это вообще не проблема, можно даже сделать анимационные эффекты без использования jQuery, на css transform и transition